# Getting Transaction error while trying to save using savechanges() in the inner loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having an issue when I attempt to call Entity Framework `SaveChanges()` from within a for each loop. The exception says that "a new transaction while one already exists in another thread". Getting lst from Linq query. So i want to save the data on completion of inner loop. Thanks.

```
foreach (keyword kwd in lst)
{        
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
       //processing
    } 
    //i need saving here.               
    db.SaveChanges();
}
//not here.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `foreach (keyword kwd in lst)` causes your error. `IQueryable` uses deferred execution, so only when you iterate the results the query will be executed. In your case that is in the `foreach` loop. But while you are fetching the data, you already start modifying it and saving it to the database -> error with transactions. The solution is to force the query to execute beforehand by calling `ToList`:

```
foreach (keyword kwd in lst.ToList())
{        
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
      //processing
   } 
   //i need saving here.               
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```